# PHP foreach alternate syntax

Tags: php, foreach

I am learning PHP from the book "Murach PHP and MySQL 2nd Edition" and I came across this code which I don't fully understand...

```
<select name="productkey">
     <?php foreach ($products as $key => $product):
            $cost = number_format($product['cost'], 2);
            $name = $product['name'];
            $item = $name . ' ($)' . $cost . ')';
     ?> 
     <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $item; ?></option>

     <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Why are there instructions after the colon (:) at the start of the foreach loop??

I read that after the colon there should be "?>" and then the instructions to execute and then at end "" to mark the end of the foreach loop...

Please explain this AND IF I WRITE THE LINES STARTING WITH $cost,$name and $item after `<?php foreach ($products as $key => $product): ?>` would the code still work???

Comment: How about trying it? Would be faster than waiting for an answer.

Comment: how about explaing the code because I'm not clear on it

Comment: PHP code must be enclosed within `<?php ?>` or `<?= ?>` tags the colon is irrelevant. Typically when using a `<?php foreach () : ?>` people put HTML right after the colon but it's not the case here.

Comment: To answer your QUESTION WITH CAPS AT THE END (rude by the way) no it will not work. Your code `<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $item; ?></option>` is using variables `$key` and  `$item` which are declared in the lines immediately following the foreach loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it would still work : is the same as { but you have to write endforeach at the end of your foreach it does the same thing more info check out this    page 
    [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: Thankyou for answering...In my code I already have an endforeach...Are you saying I need another if I move some lines of code around???

Comment: No, its just instead of the } you need to write endforeach

Answer (score 3):

`:` called an [Alternative Syntax For Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively.

It allows you to omit braces {} from a foreach to make it look cleaner and its mostly used, within templates.

Answer (score 1):

The colon is an alternative to using brackets. 
This:

```
foreach (...) :
   #execute Code in loop
endforeach;
```

is the same as this:

```
foreach (...) {
    #execute Code in loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The alternative syntax is mainly for use with mixed html content.  The main advantage is say you have something like this

```
<?php if( $var ){  ?>
<!-- some html here -->
    <?php foreach( $var as $v ){  ?>
         <!-- some html here -->
        <?php if( $v=='foo'){  ?>

            <!-- some html here -->
        <?php } ?>
    <!-- some html here -->
    <?php  } ?>
<!-- some html here -->
<?php } ?>
```

You quickly wind up with a mess of `}` everywhere,  compare to this

```
<?php if( $var ):  ?>
<!-- some html here -->
    <?php foreach( $var as $v ):  ?>
         <!-- some html here -->
        <?php if( $v=='foo'):  ?>

            <!-- some html here -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- some html here -->
    <?php  endforeach; ?>
<!-- some html here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is a small example so I don't think if fully shows the issue, but it's much easier to where the `if` blocks end and the `foreach` ends even in this.

Now multiple that by about 200 lines of mixed content.  Otherwise you can look at it as the `:` is a `{` and the `end{blocktype};` is the `}`

Personally I never use it ( except on SO ), because I don't mix HTML and PHP in my code.

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As you said it normally called PHP alternate syntax for control structure. You can read in more depth in that [article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

Alternate Syntax is normally used when we need to mix-up HTML inside PHP. In your code:

```
<select name="productkey">
 <?php foreach ($products as $key => $product):
        $cost = number_format($product['cost'], 2);
        $name = $product['name'];
        $item = $name . ' ($)' . $cost . ')';
 ?> 
 <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $item; ?></option>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can see you have a option inside foreach. In this type of case it's better to use alternate syntax. We can use the alternate syntax for **if else** and **switch case** as well.

Comment: "If you used regular PHP foreach syntax here you will find yourself in trouble to output the option inside it. " - What? What kind of trouble?

Comment: The answer is updated. Actually my intention was not that there will be any big trouble. I was just wanted to tell it's better to use alternate syntax in that type of cases

Comment: What is the value of your answer? It contains the code from OP. It contains a link that was already posted in 2 other answers. It contains a sentence that also exists in other answers. I get it, you are trying your hand in answering. But then you should write something new, what isn't already explained in the other answers.