# Technical difference between these two types foreach() loops in php?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, difference

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
            code to be executed;
} 



VS



  <?php foreach($arr as $item):?>
        <!--do stuff -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I mostly used `brackets` when using `foreach(){...}` loop , but What is `foreach(): ... endforeach;` loop for? 
Is there any difference between these two types `foreach(){} vs foreach():...endforeach;` or they are same in php? 
and in which scenario we used them or is there any technical difference between them?

and which one is the better approach for looping the resultset?

Thanks for Help Please.

Comment: The second way is used when you don't want to quote and echo your HTML, you will still have to use other PHP tags within that loop for PHP, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP foreach alternate syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119703/php-foreach-alternate-syntax)

Comment: @StackSlave sir please explain with example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are **exact** same thing with **two different syntax**.

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, **foreach**, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, **endforeach**;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

**Reference** : https://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment. These output the same thing:

**Must echo or print**

```
<?php
$array = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'];
foreach($array as $value) {
  echo "<div>$value</div>";
}
?>
```

**No echo or print of HTML *(not generated by PHP)*, needed**

```
<?php foreach($array as $item): ?>
  <div><?php echo $item; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Short tags enabled *(not necessary with <?=?> since PHP 5.4)***

```
<? foreach($array as $item): ?>
  <div><?=$item?></div>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Short tags have been disabled. The third example should not be here.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is for executing purely php code.

The second is useful for outputting HTML, as you can see, `<!--do stuff -->` is an HTML comment

Comment: please explain with example.